# How to compose functions operating with ReaderT and Either?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, monad-transformers

Is it possible to rewrite the following function as a one-liner?

```
action :: NewTenant -> AppM (Either TenantCreationError Tenant)
action newTenant = (createTenant newTenant) >>= \case
  Left x -> return $ Left x
  Right y -> do
    t <- activateTenant $ (y ^. key)
    return $ Right t

type AppM = ReaderT AppConfig IO
createTenant :: NewTenant -> AppM (Either TenantCreationError Tenant)
activateTenant :: TenantId -> AppM Tenant
```

Comment: At the cost of using [`Data.Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-3.2.0.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) (from `bifunctors`), you can map over both sides of the `Either` at once using `bimap`. That leaves you with `createTenant newTenant >>= bimap pure (\y -> activateTenant (y ^. key))` (and of course you can make the last lambda point-free too, at the cost of making things even less readable: `createTenant newTenant >>= bimap pure (activateTenant . (^. key))`).

Comment: @Alec Naively, that doesn't look like it type-checks. Won't `bimap` return an `Either` with some `AppM`s inside, when what you want is an `AppM` with an `Either` inside?

Comment: Ah yes. So you would. There there is [`uncozipL`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.3/docs/Data-Functor-Adjunction.html#v:uncozipL)  for this in one of Edward Kmett's package... :)

Comment: I have no clue about what was said above :)

Comment: @DanielWagner I believe that what I was initially looking for was actually [`bitraverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-3.2.0.1/docs/Data-Bitraversable.html) not `bimap` - not that it matters too much.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best way will be to include `ExceptT` or similar in your `AppM` monad. Then you will give new types to `createTenant` and `activateTenant`:

```
createTenant :: NewTenant -> AppM Tenant
activateTenant :: TenantId -> AppM Tenant

action :: NewTenant -> AppM Tenant
action = activateTenant . view key <=< createTenant
```

You can convert your old functions to the new monad stack with `ExceptT` (for `createTenant`) and `lift` (for `activateTenant`).

If for some reason this approach is not possible, then you could make your code suitably unreadable instead:

```
action = createTenant >=> either (return . Left) (\y -> Right <$> activateTenant (y ^. key))
```

One downside of putting `ExceptT` in your `AppM` monad is that then you have no way to distinguish between actions that can and cannot fail. If this matters to you, you have a couple choices.

1. Use `ExcepT` locally just for its instances. You would keep `AppM` as-is and the types of `createTenant` and `activateTenant` as-is, but write

   ```
   action newTenant = runExceptT $ do
       y <- ExcepT (createTenant newTenant)
       lift (activateTenant (y ^. key))
   ```

   or its one-line equivalent:

   ```
   action n = runExcepT (ExceptT (createTenant n) >>= lift . activateTenant . view key)
   ```
2. Make your actions polymorphic over their effects. You would still include `ExceptT` in the `AppM` monad, but the types of `createTenant` and `activateTenant` would now be

   ```
   createTenant :: (MonadReader AppConfig m, MonadIO m, MonadThrow TenantCreationError m)
                => NewTenant -> m Tenant
   activateTenant :: (MonadReader AppConfig m, MonadIO m)
                  => TenantId -> m Tenant

   action :: (MonadReader AppConfig m, MonadIO m, MonadThrow TenantCreationError m)
          => NewTenant => m Tenant
   action = activateTenant . view key <=< createTenant
   ```

   You would then in particular be able to give `action` the monomorphic type `AppM Tenant`; and it would still be clear from the type of `activateTenant` that it cannot fail. Moreover it would give you the opportunity to say things you couldn't say before; e.g. if `newTenant` doesn't need to do `IO` you could indicate that by removing `MonadIO m` from the constraints in its type. You can recover short type signatures by defining a type synonym for whichever combination(s) you expect to be used most often, e.g.

   ```
   type ConfigIO m = (MonadReader AppConfig m, MonadIO m)
   type Failable m = (ConfigIO m, MonadThrow TenantCreationError m)
   createTenant :: Failable m => NewTenant -> m Tenant
   activateTenant :: ConfigIO m => TenantId -> m Tenant
   ```

Comment: So, you're suggesting getting rid of `Either` altogether?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda Not at all! The `Either` is just hiding, not gone: `ExceptT e m a` is isomorphic to `m (Either e a)`. The reason `ExceptT e m a` is nicer than `m (Either e a)` is because its `Monad` instance's `(>>=)` operation takes care of destructing and reconstructing the `Either`s for you, and takes care of short-circuiting when a `Left` appears.

Comment: But, if I make `ExceptT` part of my based `AppM` monad, won't that force ALL my functions to return a `Left` or `Right`? Even if they can't really result in an error case?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda It will indeed. Whether that makes sense or not is a question to care about, for sure. One solution is the `mtl` way: you could make your actions polymorphic over the effects they have rather than declaring them to be in the `AppM` monad; then make sure the `AppM` monad has all the desired effects. This lets you declare in the type signature that some things will never error, yet build a top-level `AppM` action of appropriately monomorphic type. Otherwise you could use a local `ExceptT` just for its instances. Which approach sounds most interesting to you?

Comment: Are you referring to https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html ? Can it be mixed and matched with https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.8.3/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html easily? I was warming up to the latter based on my own research.

Comment: `This lets you declare in the type signature that some things will never error, yet build a top-level AppM action of appropriately monomorphic type. Otherwise you could use a local ExceptT just for its instances. Which approach sounds most interesting to you?` I'm not sure I understand both the options. Possible to spell out both as alternative answers?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the underlying approach is to convert (or "lift") the function to the same monad, right?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda I have expanded on the two approaches I mentioned briefly.